# Error importing wsdl into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl, webservice-client

I have eclipse Galileo and i am trying to create web service client. but i am getting IOException. Can you please help me to create service client?

wsdl : http://122.166.101.139:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc?wsdl

Error :

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/}getCheckedOutDocs is referenced but not defined.
java.io.IOException: Element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/}getCheckedOutDocs is referenced but not defined.
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(SymbolTable.java:670)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:545)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

WSDL FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="NavigationService"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization
                xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" />
            <http:BasicAuthentication
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort1_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization
                xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" />
            <http:BasicAuthentication
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort2_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization
                xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" />
            <http:BasicAuthentication
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort3_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization
                xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" />
            <http:BasicAuthentication
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
        <xsd:import
            schemaLocation="RepositoryService.xsd"
            namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
        <xsd:import
            schemaLocation="RepositoryService1.xsd"
            namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" />
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getDescendantsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q1:getDescendants"
        xmlns:q1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDescendantsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q2:getDescendantsResponse"
        xmlns:q2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getChildrenRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q3:getChildren"
        xmlns:q3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getChildrenResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q4:getChildrenResponse"
        xmlns:q4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getFolderParentRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q5:getFolderParent"
        xmlns:q5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getFolderParentResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q6:getFolderParentResponse"
        xmlns:q6="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getFolderTreeRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q7:getFolderTree"
        xmlns:q7="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getFolderTreeResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q8:getFolderTreeResponse"
        xmlns:q8="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getObjectParentsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q9:getObjectParents"
        xmlns:q9="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getObjectParentsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q10:getObjectParentsResponse"
        xmlns:q10="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q11:getCheckedOutDocs"
        xmlns:q11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="q12:getCheckedOutDocsResponse"
        xmlns:q12="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="INavigationServicePort">
    <wsdl:operation name="getDescendants">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendants"
            name="getDescendantsRequest" message="tns:getDescendantsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendantsResponse"
            name="getDescendantsResponse" message="tns:getDescendantsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildren"
            name="getChildrenRequest" message="tns:getChildrenRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildrenResponse"
            name="getChildrenResponse" message="tns:getChildrenResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderParent">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParent"
            name="getFolderParentRequest" message="tns:getFolderParentRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParentResponse"
            name="getFolderParentResponse" message="tns:getFolderParentResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderTree">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTree"
            name="getFolderTreeRequest" message="tns:getFolderTreeRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTreeResponse"
            name="getFolderTreeResponse" message="tns:getFolderTreeResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getObjectParents">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParents"
            name="getObjectParentsRequest" message="tns:getObjectParentsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParentsResponse"
            name="getObjectParentsResponse" message="tns:getObjectParentsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCheckedOutDocs">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocs"
            name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest" message="tns:getCheckedOutDocsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocsResponse"
            name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse" message="tns:getCheckedOutDocsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort"
    type="tns:INavigationServicePort">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort_policy" />
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getDescendants">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendants"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getDescendantsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDescendantsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildren"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getChildrenRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getChildrenResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderParent">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParent"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderParentRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderParentResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderTree">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTree"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderTreeRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderTreeResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getObjectParents">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParents"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getObjectParentsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getObjectParentsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCheckedOutDocs">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocs"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort1"
    type="tns:INavigationServicePort">
    <wsp:PolicyReference
        URI="#BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort1_policy" />
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getDescendants">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendants"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getDescendantsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDescendantsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildren"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getChildrenRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getChildrenResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderParent">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParent"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderParentRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderParentResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderTree">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTree"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderTreeRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderTreeResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getObjectParents">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParents"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getObjectParentsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getObjectParentsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCheckedOutDocs">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocs"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort2"
    type="tns:INavigationServicePort">
    <wsp:PolicyReference
        URI="#BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort2_policy" />
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getDescendants">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendants"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getDescendantsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDescendantsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildren"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getChildrenRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getChildrenResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderParent">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParent"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderParentRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderParentResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderTree">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTree"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderTreeRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderTreeResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getObjectParents">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParents"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getObjectParentsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getObjectParentsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCheckedOutDocs">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocs"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort3"
    type="tns:INavigationServicePort">
    <wsp:PolicyReference
        URI="#BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort3_policy" />
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getDescendants">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getDescendants"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getDescendantsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDescendantsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getChildren"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getChildrenRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getChildrenResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderParent">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderParent"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderParentRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderParentResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getFolderTree">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getFolderTree"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getFolderTreeRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getFolderTreeResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getObjectParents">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getObjectParents"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getObjectParentsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getObjectParentsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCheckedOutDocs">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/INavigationServicePort/getCheckedOutDocs"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getCheckedOutDocsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getCheckedOutDocsResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="NavigationService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort"
        binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort">
        <soap:address
            location="http://winserver2008:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc/ntlm" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort1"
        binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort">
        <soap:address
            location="http://winserver2008:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc/anonymous" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort2"
        binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort1">
        <soap:address
            location="http://winserver2008:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc/basic" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort3"
        binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort2">
        <soap:address
            location="http://winserver2008:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc/digest" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort4"
        binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_INavigationServicePort3">
        <soap:address
            location="http://winserver2008:37489/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/NavigationService.svc/kerberos" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: There is a problem with the wsdl file ... and the problem is clearly stated in the errorcode you pasted...(getCheckedOutDocs is referenced but not defined. )

Comment: Well, you need to put a bit more effort into your question, e.g. formatting your code blocks (did that already to at make them visible at least),some more explanations on what you tried, what you already did for tackling the problem etc. That would motivate more people to also put more effort into their answers.

Comment: Thnks thomas.. Please see the wsdl file on http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/fa/8116/. Actually i have to create java web service client in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import all the related XSD [RepositoryService.xsd,RepositoryServicd1.xsd] files while generating the client. Please make sure you are placing the XSD files in the same folder WSDL file is residing.